# How to set the HPROT[3] bit to zero in the ARM Cortex M4 series?

Tags: c, arm

Table 3-5 Protection signal encoding

| HPROT[3] | HPROT[2] | HPROT[1] | HPROT[0] | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Modifiable | Bufferable | Privileged | Data/Opcode |  |
| - | - | - | 0 | Opcode fetch |
| - | - | - | 1 | Data access |
| - | - | 0 | - | User access |
| - | - | 1 | - | Privileged access |
| - | 0 | - | - | Non-bufferable |
| - | 1 | - | - | Bufferable |
| 0 | - | - | - | Non-cacheable |
| 1 | - | - | - | Cacheable |

How can I access the `HPROT[3]` bit? Is there any other way to configure this bit?

Comment: I'd guess that you might use `(HPROT & 0x8) >> 3`, but there needs to be more information in the question about what `HPROT[3]` means in the table.  It probably isn't an ordinary C array reference.